# How to allow decimal input whose number of decimal places is lower than the step value of input component

Tags: lightninginput, decimal, number

I have a lightning input component with the attributes as type="number", formatter="decimal",and step="0.01". However, this seems to restrict the decimal input to be of exactly 2 decimal places. Is there any way to allow for a decimal input of one decimal place to be entered without having a "Your entry isn't a valid increment" error being shown?

Answer (score 0):

In this case change your step to `any` and that will do the job.